# Service Provider not booting in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I've created a new service provider to observe a model (`App\Providers\EloquentEventServiceProvider.php`), like so:

```php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App\Staff;
use App\Oberservers\StaffObserver;

class EloquentEventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Staff::observe(StaffObserver::class);
  }
}
```

I've also added it to the config file (`config\app.php`):

```php
return [
  ...
  'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Providers\EloquentEventServiceProvider::class,
    ...
  ]
  ...
]
```

The observer methods aren't working though. If I move `Staff::observe(StaffObserver::class);` to the `AppServiceProvider` class, it works just fine. So clearly this is an issue with getting my service provider to boot. I've tried `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan clear-compiled`, `composer update` and `composer dump` but none have work. Any help is greatly aprpeciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `Oberservers` name is wrong, as mentioned in the laravel doc [observers laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers) it should be `Observers` which means all of your observers should be within `App\Observers` instead of `App\Oberservers`.

so here we have 2 solutions :

1- if you want to keep the namespace `App\Oberservers`, you should run these 2 commands below because autoloading of the files may not work properly because we created a new folder `Oberservers`:

```
# Autoloading of files
composer dump

# Configure the cache
php artisan config:cache
```

2- the second solution is to just rename your actual `Oberservers` folder to `Observers`, in that way the autoloading of files will work well.

Comment: I double checked my spelling everywhere except there it seems... Thanks for the detailed answer!